# meta viewport not fixed, can slide left and right

Tags: html, css

I want to ask

How to create meta viewport fixed, i mean can not slide left and right

i try like this :

but not work, the page still slide left and slide right,

see my screenshoot :

[image]

i try to add overflow-x:hidden; not work to sir the page still slide left and right

how to fixed the page sir?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: thanks sir for reply, code on what sir? body css?or?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: thanks sir for reply, i use boostrap for css sir

Comment: Use something like codepen or jsfiddle or pase your formated CSS and HTML code here.

Answer (score 1):

Verify meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for reply, not work sir the page can slide left and right not fixed

Comment: You check the width of div using inspect.